# Live re-projection of web services in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-server, web-service

I am trying to provide an easy way for not-technically-literate members within my organization to access watershed subbasin delineations in ArcMap. My idea is to:

1) Pull [this USGS web service](https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/6) into ArcMap,

2) Re-symbolize and add a definition query to narrow down to the area of interest,

3) Save to a layer file on our shared drive.

This whole process works fine, but we have a standard to transform our data into our local State Plane projection (EPSG:2876), and this one comes in as Web Mercator (EPSG:3857). I would like to avoid having to host the data ourselves because I'd like for the layer to just be updated whenever USGS refines their data.

**Is there a way for me to reproject the service somewhere in this workflow so that the layer file still refers to the web service, but it's projected to our standards?**

I am relatively new to working with services, so if there's a different workflow using REST queries that can get me to the same product (a properly projected layer file), I'm all ears.

Comment: How are you pulling the service into ArcMap? If you query the service using the REST interface, you have an option to specify the output spatial reference. Try for example, the following [query](https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/6/query?where=Name+%3D+%27Pond+Creek%27&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&outSR=2876&f=html).

Comment: @MarceloVilla I "Add Data from ArcGIS Online". Since posting, I've gotten as far as you've suggested, but what I can't figure out is how to get the results of that query into ArcMap.

Comment: I frequently have to get data from ArcGIS REST services as well. My workflow is implemented using `arcpy` but you can do it manually if you want to. First, do the query and set the output format to be JSON. Save the result as a JSON file on your disk and then run the [JSON to Features tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/json-to-features.htm) using the JSON file as input.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good workflow to know about; however, my main criteria is that I don't save anything locally. Do you have your script take care of saving the output to a file?

Comment: Yes, the script takes care of everything. May I ask what you are planning to use the data for? That might help me and other people think of a more appropiate solution given your needs.

Comment: For a Minimal Working Example of the workflow I described above, check the [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/324517/86131).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll probably make use of this down the road for other analyses! We're using the data mostly as a reference. Watersheds aren't likely to change substantially, but there's still a use if we're trying to pull in live inspection data, for instance. We want as direct a connection to the source as possible without relying on scripts.